# Jekyll multidirectory portfolio website - not able to call particular files

Tags: github, blogs, jekyll

I've moved to Jekyll blogs since I wasn't using most of the features in Wordpress, and since my main is to have a portfolio I don't really need to be spending so much for hosting etc.

I'm having an issue calling my about.md file in my index.html in the about directory. The about.md file contains the information about myself (simple portfolio info. that will rarely be changed).

Currently the index.html file in about directory is:

```
---
layout: post
title: "About Me"
---

{% include head.html %}

<body class="about">

<div class="pure-g">    

    <section class="pure-u-2-3 container">
        {% include nav.html %}

    </section>

        {% include about.md %}

</div>
{% include footer.html %}
 </body>
```

As you can see I am calling the head.html + footer.html files from _include directory. I'm not sure how to call about.md though (this is the file containing info. I want shown on the page when the page is generated on the web).

Also, in which directory should about.md be? I initially had it in the root directory, but then moved it to _includes as I wanted to call it - was a right?

I'm still learning the bits and pieces of this, but can't find a tutorial.

Comment: Yes, anything you reference with an `include` call needs to go in `_includes`. Is there a specific issue you are encountering with it there?

Comment: Actually, I ended up changing the whole layout to something a lot simpler. But thanks!